# Something wrong with my variable

Tags: iphone, ios, variables, return, return-value

I created a getter to get the content of a variable, but it doesn't works.

Here the code:

```
-(void)documentURLReceived:(NSURL *)url{

    _getUrl = [[NSURL alloc] init];
    _getUrl = url;
    NSLog(@"Result: %@", _getUrl);
}
-(void)getUrl{
    NSLog(@"getUrl: %@", _getUrl);
}
```

Here the result in the consol:

> Result: `http://www.google.com`
>
> getUrl : (null)

I don't understand why!

Here my property:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSURL *getUrl;
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: where you call [self getUrl]; method?

Comment: check apples docs for naming conventions and memory management. both is important.

Comment: I'm using ARC. I call this methods in another viewcontroller: MyViewController *main = [[MyViewController alloc] init]; [main getUrl];

Comment: Waiting for the answer.......

Comment: In that case - get rid of the getURL method as you are overwriting the automatically synthesised getter/setters created by the compiler. Also your method getURL is a void method returning nothing.

Comment: Where you are calling getUrl function ? Before this documentURLReceived   function or after this documentURLReceived

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using ARC and the latest Xcode - get rid of the getURL method - you should not be overwriting this unless you need to do custom logic, furthermore, your getURL method returns nothing and is a void method - so the variable is most likely set but your method is overwriting the automatically generated getter and is returning nothing.

Did a test in Xcode

In header file I have:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURL *getURL;
```

and then in implementation file I have:

```
- (void)documentURLReceived:(NSURL *)url
{
    _getURL = url;
    NSLog(@"%@",_getURL);
}
```

> which outputs:
>
> 2013-04-04 23:29:27.681 VitalityDesignTestSuite[90518:c07]
>   http://www.google.com

okie dokie I wrote you a sample:

http://bit.ly/10yWb36

to use those you can go:

```
MyViewController *mvc = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
//Now you can set the myURL variable directly
[mvc setMyURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
NSLog(@"Direct Setting: %@",mvc.myURL);

//OR you can call the method your wrote
[mvc documentDidReceiveURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
NSLog(@"Selector Setting: %@",mvc.myURL);
```

that outputs:

2013-04-04 23:39:09.407 VitalityDesign[92197:c07] Direct Setting: http://www.google.com
2013-04-04 23:39:09.408 VitalityDesign[92197:c07] Selector Setting: http://www.google.com

hope this helps

Comment: I tried to use the method automatically generate by XCode, but it doesn't works :/

Comment: @Lapinou: try changing the name of method `-(void)getUrl{` to `-(void)getUrlMethod{` then say

Comment: I updated my answer - you sure you have the property set correctly? I can't get it not to work

Comment: Done. But doesn't works :'( Really, I don't understand why!

Comment: is documentURLReceived ever called? I notice earlier you said: MyViewController *main = [[MyViewController alloc] init]; [main getUrl]; -- assuming you got rid of the getURL selector which is good - however - when does this variable actually get set? Also your NSURL will be nil -- i'll just make you a sample gimme a sec...

Comment: updated answer. In that sample the variable is named myURL - you can call it whatever.

Comment: Yeah It works! Thank you a lot for your availability!

Comment: no worries - I know how annoying it is when something small does not work properly - glad its working now :)

Answer (score -3):

First of all are you getting anything in url?

If No,  -> Work over it

If yes then, try to do following:

```
_getUrl = [[NSURL alloc] init];
_getUrl = url;
[_getUrl retain];
NSLog(@"Result: %@", _getUrl);
```

Enjoy Programming!

Comment: You (and the OP) are leaking the empty url created on the first line when assinging a new value on the second line.

Comment: I do know very well @DavidRönnqvist,but sometimes this trick works for me..

Comment: @ForamMukundShah, you should investigate why this trick works for you. as it is just wrong

Comment: Throw in an extra retain here and there until you no longer crash from zombies?

Comment: yup, but I recommend @Lapinou, to try this once. I want to check this trick is working for him also or not. As far as I investigate this will work for him too

Comment: just because it doesnt crash doesnt mean it works

Comment: @vikingosegundo I know I need to do some research over this for sure, that why it works, although variable is propertised as strong

Comment: @ForamMukundShah, as long as you didnt fix your code, you shouldnt offer that as an answer to others.

Comment: Who up voted? OP is using ARC...retain will not work here

Comment: @AnoopVaidya, no one voted up

Comment: It was +2/-1 so I commented.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya, sometimes SO gets confused withe the votes on different posts. did u never see it before?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya, the discussion is already over, & no one has voted up. The people in the discussion including me all understood the intension of each other. Now there's no need to poke your nose in between.